# Remove class second and add new class instead

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can removed class `Second` and add new class `Third`?

I try as, but this don't work:

```
<div class="First Second"></div>

$('div').removeClass().split(" ")[1].addClass('Third');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('div').removeClass('Second').addClass('Third');
```

Answer (score 1):

[The jQuery docs are your friend](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/) in this instance. `removeClass()` takes a parameter - the classname. So change it to

```
$('div').removeClass('Second').addClass('Third')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('div').removeClass('Second').addClass('Third');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to make it dyanmic, try:

```
var divList = document.getElementsByTagName( 'div' );
var i;
for ( i = 0; i < divList.length; i++ ) {
  var thisDiv = divList[i];
  var classList = thisDiv.className.split(/\s+/);
  $( thisDiv ).removeClass( classList[1] ).addClass( 'Third' );
}​
```